# SQL query with multiple outer joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have three table with relationship as GradParent ( Country ) > Parent ( State ) > Child ( People ). I am trying to achieve a query to get distinct information on below scenario and order by Country Name.
1. All People Data with their State and Country.
2. If State doesn't have People, then State and Country Data.
3. If there is no State and/or People then just the Country Data.

Table:
[image]

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P1.ID as COUNTRY_ID, P1.NAME AS COUNTRY_NAME, P2.ID AS STATE_ID, 
P2.Name AS STATE_NAME , I1.ID AS PEOPLE_ID, I1.NAME AS PEOPLE_NAME 
FROM dbo.Country P1
    INNER JOIN dbo.State P2
        ON P2.Country_ID = P1.ID
        INNER JOIN dbo.People I1
            ON I1.Country_ID = P1.ID

    <!-- WHERE P1.Name like 'USA%'--- optional-->
    ORDER BY P1.NAME
```

Comment: Try to change your `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s

Comment: As the others commented/answered already, what you need (to produce rows for countries with no states, and for country/states with no people, is left (outer) joins, despite your title. I will edit it to reflect that. Then, your data model is not normalized (and that is not good). The PEOPLE table should only have state_id; the country of each state is already shown in the STATE table, and repeating those relationships in PEOPLE is at best redundant and at worst contradictory. I assume this is some sort of homework; I don't like your teacher, they teach bad habits with such tables.

Comment: Also - what is your database product? You have both SQL Server and Oracle, which is actually correct (having both) in only about 1% of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT OUTER` joins.  These will keep the information in the parent tables even if there are no matching child records.

Also, based on your data model, you should not need the `DISTINCT` keyword.  Throwing that in for no good reason is a bad practice.

Finally, your join condition for `PEOPLE` needs to limit by `STATE_ID`.

```
SELECT p1.id AS country_id,
       p1.name AS country_name,
       p2.id AS state_id,
       p2.name AS state_name,
       i1.id AS people_id,
       i1.name AS people_name
FROM   dbo.country p1
       LEFT JOIN dbo.state p2 ON p2.country_id = p1.id
       LEFT JOIN dbo.people i1 ON i1.country_id = p1.id AND i1.state_id = p2.id
-- WHERE P1.Name like 'USA%'--- optional--
ORDER BY p1.name, p2.name, i1.name
```

Comment: Nitpick... why the alias `p1` for `country`, `p2` for `state` and `i1` for `people`? Why not `c` for `country`, `s` for `state`, `p` for `people`?   :-) Also, the join condition 'i1.country_id = p1.id' is redundant - as soon as the state is matched correctly between `people` and `state`, and the country is matched correctly between `state` and `country`, `people and `country` will automatically be matched (or else the table contains internal contradictions - one of the possible effects of the poor, non-normal design).

Comment: He didn't post table design.  I didn't want to assume state_id is the primary key in the State table, thought it very likely is.  As far as table aliases I used what the OP used.